# Changing url using javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

i have a problem with my URL 
that is i have some thing like this

```
http://somelink.com/mobile/somethinghere
```

i need it to change it to something like this:

```
http://somelink.com/mobile/index.html
```

the **somethinghere** in the url will change dynamically i dont need that.

So is there any way to avoid that and replace it with the other.

Comment: what is the something in here?

Comment: somethinghere in the url.that will always change

Comment: somethinghere is some pages in the URL

Comment: can you give a second example, it is kind of obscure

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
location.href = 'http://somelink.com/mobile/index.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading content dynamically and don't want the url to change, use `$.load('pageToLoad', function() { })`, or modify the location of the window like this: `window.location.href='blah'`

Answer (score 0):

If Somethingthere is some page on your site, you can write some script on that page which will redirect to Index.html. I think you can use window.onload() to do that.